# Issue with vector layers in Openlayers using ES2015

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, openlayers

I have experience with regular openlayers (using the cdn or downloading the .js files) but recently I started to try the npm ol package with Angular 5.
Create a map is not a proble, but when I try to add a vector Layer, I always get an error in Chrome telling me that Vector is not a constructor. This is the code I'm using :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Map from 'ol/map';
import View from 'ol/view';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/xyz';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/geojson';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source/vector';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer/vector';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    map : Map;
    countriesLayer : VectorLayer;
    countriesSource : VectorSource;


   constructor() { }

   renderMap() {

    let url = 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    let features = 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson'

      this.map = new Map({
          view : new View({
              center : [0, 0],
              zoom : 2
          }),
          layers : [
              new TileLayer({
                  source : new XYZ({
                      url : url
                  })
              })

          ],
          target : "map"
      });

  }

  addVectorLayer() {

      this.countriesSource = new VectorSource({
          url : features,
          format : new GeoJSON()
      });


      this.countriesLayer = new VectorLayer({
          source : this.countriesSource
      });


      this.map.addLayer(this.countriesLayer);

  }


}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think both `'ol/source/vector'` and `'ol/layer/vector'` provide default exports. Try without the alias:

```
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/vector';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
```

Comment: For OpenLayers >= v5 the imports would be:

    import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
    import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';

The relevant imports are now shown at the top of each page in the API docs. For instance see VectorLayer: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html